# Xampp Fatal Error, ¿Alquien Sabe corregir el siguiente error?

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

No puedo abrir phpAdmin

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\RecentFavoriteTable.php on line 411

Answer (score 0):

El error te dice que has excedido el tiempo de procesamiento asignado al PHP. Este tiempo lo puedes configurar en tu PHP.ini. aumentas el tiempo a lo que necesites la linea que habla de **max_execution_time**

Dicho esto, deberias mostrar tambien que es lo que le pides al servidor para que tarde tanto, igual es conveniente pensar un rato para optimizar la petición...

Un saludo